# Java dnd gray box

Tags: java, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to make a Google Chrome tabs port for Java.

How do I get rid of the **gray box around dragged source** (highlighted in red)?

Everything else is working fine so far but that gray box is driving me insane.

[image]

Another example from DND example while dragging text.
The "problem" is that gray border.

[image]

Comment: Without code there is no way we can guess what is going on here.

Comment: I don't want to use ghost images or overlap GlassPane, I just want to (somehow) turn off that cursor modification while dragging.

Comment: in every example of Dnd application there is a gray box (by default) during drag from source to target.

I was trying to "google" that problem but the only solutions I found were how to show dragged content during drag (with ghost images). I don't need that. I need only NOT TO MODIFY my cursor while I drag something.

It reminds me of MS Win resizing back in the day, big ugly gray box...

Comment: Its not written in my code its not drawn by me its just a "feature" of "feedback to user" that he/she is dragging something.

And because I manage my drag feedback on my own I don't want that gray box. Is it that hard?

the Tab is in "mid drag"

Comment: I'm assuming from your comments that you have implemented a custom `TransferHandler` subclass to drag from a custom component of your own. That has never caused a "gray box" in my experience (and I'm also on Mac). So I can't really help you without seeing code.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution in DragHandler source code:

to erase the gray box, you need to do nothing in paintIcon

```
protected Icon getDragIcon(DragGestureEvent e, Point offset) {
            return new Icon() {
                public int getIconWidth() { return 0; }
                public int getIconHeight() { return 0; }
                public void paintIcon(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y) {

                }
            };
        }
```